# fail when I modify a textview in remote service

Tags: android, textview

I am making an Android app which uses a remote service and works fine, but when I want show in a textview results of this service crashes and I don't know why.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.grafica;

import com.example.pruebacelia.IRemoteService;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    float ancho = (float) 5.20;
    float largo = (float) 3.50;
    private SurfaceView surface;
    private TableLayout table, table2;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params, params2;
    IRemoteService mRemoteService;
    private int i = 0;
    private Thread serviceThread = null;
    private Paint pincel = new Paint();
    private Canvas canvas;
    private TextView tx1, tx2, tx3;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.viewland);
        }

        surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surface.getHolder().addCallback(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                float xini = 0;
                float yini = 0;
                float xend = 0;
                float yend = 0;

                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                pincel.setStrokeWidth(8);
                pincel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                RectF rect = new RectF();

                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;
                int height = size.y;

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                    params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) table.getLayoutParams();

                    float ratio = ancho / largo;
                    float aux = width / ratio;

                    params.topMargin = (int) aux + 20;

                    xini = 20;
                    yini = 20;
                    xend = width - 20;
                    yend = aux;

                }

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                    table2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);
                    params2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) table2
                            .getLayoutParams();

                    float ratio = largo / ancho;
                    float aux = width / ratio;

                    params2.leftMargin = (int) (width * ratio) + 20;

                    xini = 20;
                    yini = 20;
                    xend = width * ratio;
                    yend = height - 220;

                }

                rect.set(xini, yini, xend, yend);
                canvas.drawRect(rect, pincel);

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
                canvas.drawPoint(xini, yend, pincel);

                pincel.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
                canvas.drawPoint(xend, yend, pincel);

                pincel.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
                canvas.drawPoint(xini, yini, pincel);

                pincel.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
                canvas.drawPoint(xend, yini, pincel);

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });
        
        
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setClassName("com.example.pruebacelia",
                "com.example.pruebacelia.DemoService");
        boolean ok = bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.v("ok", String.valueOf(ok));


    }

    
    
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // get instance of the aidl binder
            mRemoteService = IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(service);

            i = 0;
            serviceThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (i == 0) {
                        try {
                            float message = mRemoteService.getx();
                            
                            float message2 = mRemoteService.gety();
                            
                            float message3 = mRemoteService.getz();
                            
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            Log.e("RemoteException", e.toString());
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                tx1.setText(String.valueOf("ei"));
                                
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, "serviceThread");
            serviceThread.start();

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evento) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            i = 1;
            Log.i("telo", "pulsado");
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            finish();

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In concret when I do the .settext();

and this is logcat:

```
02-11 09:55:41.579: I/Adreno-EGL(9499): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
02-11 09:55:41.599: D/OpenGLRenderer(9499): Enabling debug mode 0
02-11 09:55:41.739: D/AndroidRuntime(9499): Shutting down VM
02-11 09:55:41.739: W/dalvikvm(9499): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41548ba8)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499): Process: com.example.grafica, PID: 9499
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at com.example.grafica.MainActivity$1$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:217)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-11 09:55:41.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 09:55:42.309: D/dalvikvm(9499): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 191K, 2% free 17078K/17300K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
02-11 09:55:43.909: I/Process(9499): Sending signal. PID: 9499 SIG: 9
```

Comment: this:  tx1.setText(String.valueOf("ei"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content of the layout to the activity first then initialize views

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    // this should be first
    tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    // then initialize views
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. If not you end up i `NullPointerException`.

Comment: ok... thanks!!! the problems is that i comprobe the orientation of screen to select between differents views and not load view before load textview! thanks so much

Comment: @user3243651 then initialize after `setContentView`. can't initialize before setting the layout to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

Give the `TextView` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.viewland);
        }



        tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your onCreate method() below super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and after that initialize your text

Like this :-

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    setContentView(R.layout.viewland);
}



tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
```